# Calculating a p-value from permutations

Tags: distributions, sampling

I have 500 genes I am interested in. I want to test whether they are enriched in a certain dataset (Y).
Y is a list of cancer genes that are called cancer genes at different levels of likelihood. I.e. they have a p-value assigned to them on how likely they are to be cancer genes.

I have generated a null distribution by randomly sampling 1000 sets of 500 other genes from my dataset (accounting for certain biases), and test how many are present in Y at a certain p-value threshold (0.00001 for example). In my observed dataset 300 of the 500 are cancer genes with p < 0.00001.

If I have 20 of my 1000 permutation sets that have more genes that are p < 0.00001 compared to my observed list, how can I quantify this?

I want to calculate an enrichment p value.

Comment: p-value is not likelihood. How were the p-values obtained? (Importantly, for understanding what you intend by your question and possible answers -- do you know what a p-value is?)

Comment: I didn't mean statistical likelihood. Those genes have been associated to cancer with different levels of association (quantified with a p-value) - I'm classifying those genes at a certain FDR to be highly confident cancer genes.

Comment: So the p value represents the probability of those genes not being cancer genes. (A hypothetical example BTW)

Comment: Your idea of a p-value looks to be wrong. This will impact the understanding of your question.

Comment: I'm quite aware of what a p-value is. It's the probability I have calculated from a separate analyses of rejecting the null hypothesis when H0 is actually true. That H0 was: 'the gene isn't involved in cancer'.

Therefore I would like to compare the genes I have (500); of which, 300 are potentially cancer related genes, to that of a randomly sampled list of genes (500x1000). To quantify this, I would like a p-value that is calculated from the fact X genes are observed to be cancer genes compared to Y number of permutations that had more than X.

Comment: Updated question with image as it seems easier to explain.

Comment: The probability of rejecting the null hypothesis when it is actually true, that is the probability of a Type I error, is called the significance level, commonly $\alpha$. This is _not_ the same thing as a p-value.

Comment: Okay -- you understand what a p-value is -- but then you cannot fail to see the problem I was concerned about. Let me quote your question: "they have a p-value assigned to them on how likely they are to be cancer genes" ... That is not consistent with the definition of p-value you gave. A p-value doesn't tell you the probability they are cancer genes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to chose a statistic $T$ first. For example, you can set
$$ T = - \sum_{i=1}^{500} \log p_i $$
where $p_i$ is the "cancer gene $p$ value" (for those genes which are not in $Y$, I suggest to set $p_i = 1$).

Now you have an observed value $T_{obs}$. A high value means "lots of genes with small cancer gene $p$ values", which is, I guess, what you wish. To assess the significance of the particular value $T_{obs}$ you obtained, compute $T$ for (e.g.) 1000 random samples of 500 genes on the genome to estimate
$$\mathbb P(T > T_{obs})$$
as the proportion of permuted $T$ which exceed $T_{obs}$.

Other choices are possible for $T$. If you are only interested in the presence/absence in the list $Y$, not in the computed $p$, simply take $T = {}$number of genes in $Y$. You can also count how many are in $Y$ with $p < 10^{-5}$, or anything. You have to motivate your choice. Taking the log as suggested above is somehow natural and should not be too questioned. However, the way the list $Y$ is constituted, and what you’re really trying to test, should be explained carefully.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

'simply take T=number of genes in Y. You can also count how many are in Y with p<10−5'

So simply, if 10 of my 1000 permutations have more genes present at p > 10-5 than my observed, can I do 10/1000 = 0.01 as p?

Comment: Yes, you can (did you mean $p < 10^{-5}$?). But I am not sure that I would be convinced that you didn’t chose the threshold $10^{-5}$ a posteriori. If you chose this strategy, you should show the results with different thresholds to convince your reader that your 500 genes "are more associated to cancer" than a random set of 500 genes.

Comment: Hi Elvis, thanks again. That's exactly what I have done. I have generated permutations and overlapped at high-low stringency thresholds based on p.

Comment: What if no permutations were less than my observed?

0/1000 =

Comment: You state only $p < 10^{-3}$.